# Open Source solution to batch process shortest distance between points along road networks?

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations, routing

I have the locations geocoded (a fairly small dataset, ~200), but I haven't found a straightforward way to load these data into QGIS and perform network analysis between nodes.

Any suggestions?

I'm aware of the Road graph plugin, but I don't know how to load a batch of data.

I've also tried to figure out how to do this with TOPOJSON and d3.js without much success.

Comment: you mention 'haven't found a straightforward way to load these data...' - is that one question? If so, what is the format of the data?

Comment: The format of the data is variable: it's currently in a CSV, but that's easily modified to JSON or MySQL in a couple keystrokes (or a shape file, but from everything I've seen, it's easier to work with it in another format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest Grass GIS.  The v.net package is a pretty powerful tool.  Grass can be a bit tricky to get going on but with a tutorial or two you should be OK.
You will also need to interpret the matrix result that will be ~200 by ~200 with the distances. Export to excel, import with Python, etc. and do what needs doing with it.

http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.net.allpairs.html

Answer (score 3):

If you have a well made road graph shape (with from and to nodes), you can use my qgis processing scripts at

https://github.com/chourmo/QGIS-Transit-tools

For batch starting points, use Shortest-times car
If you want to find times from start to end, make a lines files and use Shortest-path car